# Choosing a smarthost based on From: address (sender's address) in Exim4 on Debian

Tags: regex, debian, pcre, exim4

This question is about the use of regular expressions with Exim, so
while it is a bit exotic, I believe it is on topic here. If the consensus is that this is not the case, I would appreciate suggestions about where to post it.

I am using Exim 4.94.2-7 on Debian 11.6 (bullseye), and I'm also using the Debian configuration system for Exim4, which involves files like `/etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf`.

I have been trying to configure Exim to select the smarthost based on
the From address (the sender's address). The solution described by
Marc Auslander
[[debian-user] exim4 smarthost selection based on sender](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2022/11/msg00881.html) works for me, though it may not be perfect.

For more context on this, see the first post by me in the thread at
[[Pkg-exim4-users] How to choose a smarthost based on From: address in Exim4](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/pkg-exim4-users/2023-March/thread.html#2468)

My slightly adapted version of Marc Auslander's solution sets the
value for dc_smarthost in /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf as
follows.

```
dc_smarthost='"${if match{${lc:$header_from:}}{.*gmail.com}{smtp.gmail.com::587}{${if match{${lc:$header_from:}}{.*mydomain}{smtp.mailbox.org::587}{secure-email-32.luxsci.com::587}}}}"'
```

This uses syntax as described in
[[Exim Internet Mailer] Chapter 11 - String expansions](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html)
in Section 5: Expansion items, namely

```
 ${if <condition> {<string1>}{<string2>}}
```

and Section 7: Expansion conditions, namely

```
 match {<string1>}{<string2>}
```

Alternatively, if you have the official Exim book, "The Exim SMTP Mail
Server" (my version is "Official Guide for Release 4", First Edition,
published 2003), this syntax is discussed in Section 17.7, with
`match` covered in Section 17.7.3.

In pseudocode, this is

```
if the from header matches the regex .*gmail.com
    then
        use smtp.gmail.com::587
else if the from header matches .*mydomain
    then
        use smtp.mailbox.org::587
else # default if nothing else matches
        use secure-email-32.luxsci.com::587
```

This works for me, though there may be some problematic edge
cases. However, I get a strange error when I try to modify it as
follows.

```
dc_smarthost='"${if match{${lc:$header_from:}}{.*gmail.com}{smtp.gmail.com::587}{${if match{${lc:$header_from:}}{.*mydomain|.*mailbox.org}{smtp.mailbox.org::587}{secure-email-32.luxsci.com::587}}}}"'
```

This is similar to the previous version, but in terms of pseudocode,
this just replaces

```
else if the from header matches .*mydomain
```

with

```
else if the from header matches .*mydomain|.*mailbox.org
```

i.e. the from header matches either `.*mydomain` or `.*mailbox.org`.

The error is:

```
Mar 30 01:59:54 orwell exim4[3626569]: sed: -e expression #1, char 861: unknown option to `s'
```

I did a search for this error, and it most commonly seems to happen
when `sed` is trying to process text with forward slashes. But I have
no idea what this error means here. As far as I can tell I'm using the
syntax correctly; Exim4 uses PCRE regular expressions.

Explanations of this error would be much appreciated. A version of
this regex that works would be even more appreciated. Additionally, if
you see any problems with the general approach, please let me
know. The other solutions I've seen all involve transports, routers,
and lots of boilerplate, and look quite complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set up a router for each smarthost, and use the `senders` selector to determine which one is used.

```
gmail_router:
   router = manualroute
   senders = gmail.com
   transport = remote_smtp_smarthost
   route_list = * smtp.gmail.com::587 by_dns
```

or similar.